# Why does `inclusive` not work in this wordpress loop?

Tags: loop

It's seemingly simple, I have this loop which should loads posts from, and including the current post.

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
  $catID[] = $category->cat_ID;
} 
$args = array(
    'category__in' = > $catID,
    'category__not_in' = > 1,
    'posts_per_page' = > 10,
    'date_query' = > array(
        array(
            'before' = > get_the_date()
        ),
        'inclusive' = > true, 
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop -> have_posts()) {
$loop -> the_post();
  get_template_part( 'sidebar-posts-template' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

The problem is that it doesn't **include** the current post. Why?

Edit: This loop, using a fixed date also does not work and will start loading posts from the 27th, not including the 28th. The `inclusive` date should include posts from the 28th.

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' = > array(
        array(
            'after' = > 'January 1st, 2013',
            'before' = > array(
                'year' = > 2013,
                'month' = > 2,
                'day' = > 28, 
             ),
            'inclusive' = > true, 
        ), 
    ),
    'posts_per_page' = > -1, );
```

Edit 2: This is now the loop I am using.

```
$args = array(
    'category__in' => $catID,
    'category__not_in' => 1,
    'posts_per_page'=>10,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'before' => get_the_date(),
            'inclusive' => true, 
        ),
    )
);
```

Edit 3:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'=>10,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
          'before'    => array(
         'year'  => 2013,
         'month' => 2,
         'day'   => 28,
           ),
          'inclusive' => true 
        ),
     )
);
```

Comment: Please take better care with your syntax. Your issue is that you have the `inclusive` parameter inside the *wrong array*, which is readily apparent when you use proper code indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Edit 3

Now, combine Edits 1 and 2:

```
'date_query' = > array(
    array(
        'before' = > strtotime( get_the_date() ),
        'inclusive' = > true, 
    )
)
```

## Edit 2

You don't have your `inclusive` parameter inside the correct array.

Change this:

```
'date_query' = > array(
    array(
        'before' = > get_the_date()
    ),
    'inclusive' = > true, 
)
```

...to this:

```
'date_query' = > array(
    array(
        'before' = > get_the_date(),
        'inclusive' = > true, 
    )
)
```

## Edit

The `get_the_date()` function must be used *inside the loop*, because it relies on the `$post` global.

The `get_the_date()` function also returns a *date-formatted string*, but the `date_query` `before` parameter accepts a *`strtotime()`* compatible string.

Instead of this:

```
'before' => get_the_date()
```

...try this:

```
'before' => strtotime( get_the_date() )
```

## Original Answer

The `inclusive` parameter is part of the [`WP_Query()` `date_query` parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters), and must be used inside of the array passed to `date_parameter`. Refer to the example usage in the Codex:

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => 'January 1st, 2013',
            'before'    => array(
                'year'  => 2013,
                'month' => 2,
                'day'   => 28,
            ),
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Hi, Chip, that's the way I originally done it but ended up fiddling with it because it didn't work. If I use that exact same query in your answer my posts start from the 27th instead of the 28th so the inclusive still doesn't work

Comment: Your `date_query` syntax was wrong. Please see edit.

Comment: Hi, Chip, yes I've noticed that but even when I used a fixed date, like the one in the example, it still does not work which seems to me like a pretty big problem. I'll edit my question to show you the exact arguments I'm using now.

Comment: The problem remains the same: the `inclusive` parameter is **inside the wrong array**. Syntax, including code indentation, is critical to debugging.

Comment: :) Hi, Chip, I've tried your edit:2 and it still does not work. I must apologize for my syntax, it looks especially bad on here as I'm just copying and pasting and that is how it pastes in to the box. It's more readable on my end.

Comment: "*I've tried your edit:2 and it still does not work.*" please **edit your question** with the actual code you tried, and explain what the output was (including a live link if possible). "does not work" is not usually enough information for us to help diagnose/solve the issue. :)

Comment: Okay, I just edited my question with the loop I'm using, I'll also make it live (doesn't matter) so I can send a link.

Comment: Did you happen to notice **Edit 1**? You need a `strtotime()`-compatible string passed to `before`. See Edit 3.

Comment: Hi, here's a link, using the new loop, you can see that it is not including the current post and its date. http://lartmagazine.co.uk/fashion-pick-of-the-day-paisley-jacquard-peplum-top/

Comment: Yes, I did use that but it breaks, literally fails completely. `'before' = > strtotime( get_the_date() )` does not work.

Comment: "does not work" still is not helpful. What **debug information** do you get when it *literally fails completely*? PHP notice? Fatal error?

Comment: Oh yea, sorry, there was a syntax error, fixed it, but now it just doesn't load any posts whatsoever, using `strtotime`.

Comment: What output do you get? Is `var_dump()` `NULL`, or something else? What is the value of `get_option( 'date_format' )`? What happens if you pass an explicit string format to `get_the_date()`?

Comment: If I `var_dump` `strtotime` it gives me "1360195200" for the date 'February 7, 2013'. If I use an explicit date "2013,2,28" instead of `get_the_date()` it still does not include 28th and will start from the 27th.

Comment: I meant `var_dump( $query )`. Anyway: what are your timezone settings? What is your offset?

Comment: `echo get_option('gmt_offset');` and
`echo get_option('timezone_string');` gives me "1 Europe/London"

Comment: What is the actual post date and time for the October 2nd post?

Comment: What do you mean? The actual post date and time is "Published on: Oct 2, 2013 @ 6:33"

Comment: And next question: can you recreate the issue using a default-install of WordPress (core-bundled Theme, no Plugins) with test data?

Comment: Check Edit 3, I used that exact loop and it still didn't include the 28th and just output from the 27th.

Comment: See my previous question: can you recreate the issue using a default-install of WordPress (core-bundled Theme, no Plugins) with test data?

Comment: Please take extensive discussion to chat, this is too much for comments.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I tried that in 2014 core theme and still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems using `get_the_date()` so I ended up getting the post date as it is in the database.

```
<? php
global $post;
$postTime = $post -> post_date;
$args = array(
    'category__in' => $catID,
    'category__not_in' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'date_query' => array(
array(
    'before' => $postTime,
    'inclusive' => true 
), ));
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop -> have_posts()) {
    $loop -> the_post();
    get_template_part('sidebar-posts-template');
}
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

The important piece of code is

```
global $post;
$postTime = $post -> post_date;
```

The variable `$postTime` is what made `inclusive` work.

Comment: "`get_the_date` is not an acceptable value for `strtotime`* - this isn't actually true. `strtotime()` will take any properly formatted date/time string. `get_the_date( $d )` will output whatever date/time string you specify, as `$d`. The default value is `get_option( 'date_format' )`, which is why I asked you what that default value was.

Comment: Ah, I don't understand what you mean. So, what am I supposed to put into `get_the_date()` to get a format that works with `strtotime` and `inclusive`? Could you give me an example?

Comment: `strtotime()` should take any properly formatted date/time string. If it were me, I would use `get_the_date( get_option( 'time_format' ) )`.

Comment: Use get_the_date( 'c' ) if you need a string format that will be easily parsable by the strtotime function. This will produce an ISO 8601 formatted date string, and that will eliminate the guesswork involved.